# Drupal site that points to a non-drupal .html page

Tags: nodes

I'd like to configure my Drupal 6's site's front page to be "foo/index.htm", a hand-coded html file. But when I put that relative URL into Home › Administer › Site configuration › Default Front Page, it complains "The path 'foo/index.htm' is either invalid or you do not have access to it." It's a unix filesystem and everything is world-read, and the directories are world-execute. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the path in question here must be a valid Drupal path, not a Unix path/filename.  I'd suggest investigating [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu/6) as a first step of learning about Drupal paths, callbacks and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The code that is causing that error is part of the form validation handler for the form you are submitting. (See [system_site_information_settings_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_site_information_settings_validate/7).)

```
// Validate front page path.
if (!drupal_valid_path($form_state['values']['site_frontpage'])) {
  form_set_error('site_frontpage', t("The path '%path' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.", array('%path' => $form_state['values']['site_frontpage'])));
}
```

[drupal_valid_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7) considers the passed path valid if:

- It is `<front>`
- It is considered external, i.e. an absolute path starting with the protocol string
- It is a path defined from a module

Notice that the form validation handler doesn't check the value for the front page path is a relative path, but [drupal_is_front_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) contains the following code.

```
$is_front_page = ($_GET['q'] == variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
```

This means the path for the front page needs to be relative.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually look at modifying the `.htaccess` file to serve your HTML file instead of Drupal's `index.php` when someone attempts to visit your homepage.

If you look at the [`.htaccess`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/6.x/.htaccess#L109) file provided by Drupal, it only serves `index.php` when a file or directory does not exist on the server (lines 109-113). You can put a new rule right before that and tell Apache that rule should be the last rule run (which will skip any remaining rules if the conditions are matched). I think the following should work (based on the answer [Htaccess rule to redirect domain to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911417/htaccess-rule-to-redirect-domain-to-index-html)):

```
RewriteRule ^$ foo/index.html [L]
```

As long as that rule runs before the Drupal rule that routes all traffic through `index.php`, it should serve your homepage instead of the default Drupal homepage. This will work as long as your homepage has a URL like `http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/` and the user doesn't type anything else (like `index.php` or `index.html`). You'll also need to make sure that all links to the homepage inside Drupal point to the correct URL (for example, the logo link, etc).

Also, because this is a modification to the `.htaccess` file, you'll need to make sure to copy the change over to the new `.htaccess` file when doing Drupal core updates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Front Page](https://drupal.org/project/front) module, in the configuration page, 'Home links' tab, set to 'xxx.html'.
2. Done.